# Python package for implementing branch-and-bound technique for solving a non-convex non-linear integer multi-objective optimization problem?

Tags: python, optimization, package, nonlinear-optimization, non-convex

[image]

Here, X1 and X2 take integer values. I want to use branch-and-bound technique to solve this problem. What are the python tools available to solve this problem?

Comment: This question may be useful to you: https://scicomp.stackexchange.com/questions/19870/python-solvers-for-mixed-integer-nonlinear-constrained-optimization

Comment: pyomo + couenne.